# How to tell if the file can be overridden?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, overrides

How do we alter the output of a Plugin that is installed in a Component (Example: "ABC" plugin installed in a Component "ABCD")? I understand that the core files can't be overridden. But how do we tell which one is the core file and which file is not the core file and it can be overridden?

I checked the "Create Overrides" tab but the plugin "ABC" is not available even though it is installed and enabled.

Referring to all components, modules and plugins. How to write the override path for it? Is there an override folder structure that we need to follow if it is a component, module or plugin?

Apologise for the initial question that was too broad and unclear.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take a moment to take the [tour]. I am afraid your question needs a bit "more". Good questions that attract good answers are: clear, detailed, show research and effort.  Please try to narrow your question and provide context so that volunteers will know exactly what you are trying to do; this will, in turn, allow them to offer you very specific and educational support.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the component and plugin your are trying to override and someone maybe be able to provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any layout or view can be overridden in Joomla.

You can do this in your Joomla admin panel, by going to:

> Extensions (top menu) >> Templates >> Templates >> Details and Files

Once there, go to the "Create Overrides" tab, and you will be able to select your component annd the view.

So let's say you create an override for **com_content/archive**. This will oveeride the files in the following directory:

> ROOT/components/com_content/views/archive/tmpl

and create the overrides in:

> ROOT/templates/your_template/html/com_content/archive

If you compare the paths, you'll get a better idea of how the override path is created.

Comment: We tried the "Create Overrides" tab, the file doesn't seem to show up there. The file is stored in Plugins folder, it is a plugin of a component and we want to edit the output for that. According to the component developer, not all files can be overridden especially the core file, but how do we know whether it is a core file or cannot be overridden?

Comment: Plugins don't use the same standard views and components and modules. If the plugin utilised layouts, that would be a different story and overrides would be possible.

Comment: @user2976317 see why it is important to be very clear and specific about your issue from the beginning? Now a volunteer is having to chase your subsequently revealed details and will need to edit their post.  Please update your question -- the "full story" is meant to be in the question body (not spread out over comments).  Your question, as it is currently written, is vulnerable to being closed as Too Broad or Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about what is core and what isn't when you look at the extensions under the Extensions->Manage->Manage menu look at the ID column on the far right and if the ID is less than 999(or only has three digits) then it is core, if it above 10000 then it is 3rd party.

If the site has been progressively migrated from early versions of Joomla this may not hold true, but a for most cases it does.